# Mathematical description of problem where sample is asked about three most liked brands?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have a population of *branded products* lets say diary food and want to know which brand is the most liked.
I ask 1001 people to tell me their *three most liked brands*. What is the mathematical description of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You ask an open-ended question, so responses are formatted (worded) freely. You have to categorize responses into bins of same or similar foods before you can produce summary statistics for the study. To decide that responces A and B are similar enough to constitute the same food for you you need to decide first where similarity between various foods ends and dissimilarity starts. This implies that you need to have pre-existent concept of whole population of foods. Thereby it cannot be infinite population for you anymore.

Comment: makes sense to me. I will refine the question

Answer (score 1):

If you ask different set of brands each time. For example compare two of them or choose among 5. Then it can be solved as Descriptive choice algorithm to select best among others.

Comment: Do you have a description of descriptive choice algo?

Comment: I preffer Rank Maximum Entropy you can find implementation and some theory in lingpipe http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/dca/DiscreteChooser.html